# Is it possible to move android app on Java Smart card and later install it on phone when card is close to phone with NFC interface?

Tags: android, nfc, javacard, apdu

I have an application which communicates through NFC/APDU with JavaCard. THe problem is that when there is no application installed, the communication is not working.

I would like to find solution to have this app on Java Card and upload it to android phone to handle JavaCard request.

I was looking for such solution, but i didnt find any similar.

Thanks for answers:).

Comment: How could an app be uploaded from card to phone if communication is not working?

Comment: JavaCard is comunicating with android app, so when no app installed there is no possibility to communicate. So I need the way to upload android application first to the phone.

Comment: Oh boy, if it were possible to upload code to a smartphone via NFC, ... You will have to think of an incentive to download your app first, no way around that. (Would it even be practical / technically possible to store a whole .apk file on a Smart Card?)

Comment: Android app is very small and JavaCard may have quite a lot of memory these days like 128KB.

Answer (score 1):

This could work: instead of uploading an entire app from the card to the phone, something that would be extremely hard (if at all possible) why don't you code an NDEF tag with a URL pointing to your app in Google Play, so that the user can download and install the app from there?

Comment: Thanks for answer.How to add this NDEF tag to card? with applet code?

Comment: Yes. An example is this project by a friend of mine: an implementation of an NDEF tag using JavaCard. Link: https://github.com/slomo/ndef-javacard